# How to check SPM repo link in xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager

I am trying to check repo link for my existing project already added SPM.

I want to know the repo link for github/bitbuckect etc etc.

**Why i wanted to know this** - I have one existing project in which lots of SPMs are there. and I want to add all that SPM in my new project but I don’t know git links for those SPM.

Is there any way to do that?

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Package.swift file in the root of your repo, that should also contain the links, if not, try the below one:

[image]On the left pane, each of the dependencies will have a .podspec file with a s.source specification. You can find the URL there.

Answer (score 2):

The root source of this information can be found inside the project file (`./<project_name>.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj`). Just open it with text editor and search for occurrences of `XCRemoteSwiftPackageReference`. You should be able to find sections like this one:

```
/* Begin XCRemoteSwiftPackageReference section */
    A1BFE4BB2779F1410015B840 /* XCRemoteSwiftPackageReference "swift-atomics" */ = {
        isa = XCRemoteSwiftPackageReference;
        repositoryURL = "https://github.com/apple/swift-atomics.git";
        requirement = {
            kind = upToNextMajorVersion;
            minimumVersion = 1.0.0;
        };
    };
/* End XCRemoteSwiftPackageReference section */
```